# Why does kernel die after executing command for reading grib2 file with xarray with engine cfgrib

Tags: python, python-xarray, cfgrib

I am using a `jupyter notebook` running on `Ubuntu18 OS` with `Python3`

After executing the command

```
import xarray as xr
import pyeccodes
import eccodes 
import cfgrib
my_data = xr.open_dataset('mydata.grib2' , engine='cfgrib')
```

The kernel dies.

I think the issue is related with grib files with different typeOfLevel (see [this issue](https://github.com/ecmwf/cfgrib/issues/2))

Comment: Try running the same script in a non-Jupyter context to see if it works.

Comment: Does it immediately die? If not, it may be running out of memory

Comment: @Maximilian,the issue is actually related to an error.  it was a really rare behavior: instead of showing the Error, the kernel died